# CreateWindowW window is too small

Tags: c++, winapi

When I create my window, it is smaller than the width and height specified, that should be 840x840. The actual window created is only approx 825x782 (not including menus etc). I can't work out why the window is small and have never had this problem before. Thanks in advance.

```cpp
CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 200, 840, 840,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: `The actual window created is only approx 825x782 (not including menus etc)` Because the size you specify __does__ include border and menus.

Comment: Are you referring to the size of the client area?  The dimensions passed to `CreateWindow` include caption bar, the menu (if any) and the borders, so the client area will be somewhat smaller than this.

Comment: Your 10th parameter must be handle to program instance `GetModuleHandle(nullptr)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindoww

Comment: Maybe you should call AjustWindowRectEx before calling CreateWindow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-adjustwindowrectex

Comment: [Application Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-windows#application-windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use AdjustWindowRect function as commented by Simon Mourier, where `rect` is the size of the client window.

```cpp
RECT rect = {0, 0, width, height};
AdjustWindowRect(&rect, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, true);

CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 200, 
        rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, 
        NULL, NULL, hPrevInst, NULL);
```